# Worklight_HydribApp_PushNotification for Windows Phone 8 Using MPNS

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, keystore, ibm-mobilefirst, mpns

Hi we have developed an application using **IBM MobileFirst Studio 7.0.0**,In order to send notifications for Android and IOS Platforms we used GCM and APNS respectively and everything worked fine coming to Windows Phone 8 application we are planning to go with **MPNS(Microsoft Push Notification Services)** concept.

As per MPNS is concerned we are planning to go with Authenticated push services which can give us unlimited access to send notifications, we require a **Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate keystore** for the same.

The keystore can contain several certificates, one of which is the certificate for authenticated push notifications to MPNS.
**To use MPNS concept we need certificate which is authenticated push notifications.**

How to generate that certificate and do we need any web service to develop MPNS Push Notification for **Windows Phone 8**?

as part of my research followed [this link](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_WP8.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you have found, you will see how to generate a SSL Keystore and certificates - [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_ssl_certificate_keystore_setup.html). Once you have the certificates, login to Windows Development center and upload the certificate there. Instructions on how to do this can be found in the following links:

[Setting up an authenticated web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941099(v=vs.105).aspx)

[Enabling no-quota push notifications](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/12/10/enabling-no-quota-push-notifications-for-company-apps-on-windows-phone/)

[No-quota push notifications](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/06/06/no-quota-push-notifications-using-a-root-certificate-authority/)

Comment: Thanks a ton , it really helps me a lot @Vivin K